# How to select the rows where a condition is satisfied

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, extract

Consider three numpy arrays:

```
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) 
y = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
z = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

How can I produce an array from `x`, where a condition is satisfied involving `y` and `z`.
For example `"extract x where y+z = 2"` would return:

```
np.array([3, 7])
```

(as I have a lot of data, I want this to be as fast as possible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> y = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
>>> z = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])

>>> y + z == 2
array([False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)

# here y+z==2 returns a boolean array that can be used to index x
>>> x[y + z == 2]
array([3, 7])
```

Comment: If pure speed is the concern an alternative would be `(y.astype(np.bool) & z.astype(np.bool))` for this particular case. Asymptotically twice as fast.